# Extract Part of a Web Scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've scraped a certain portion of a website and now need to extract certain parts (company ticker) of that code.
Here is the html code:

```
<table class="wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 325px;">Company</th>
        <th style="width: 65px;" class="wsod_aRight">Price</th>
        <th style="width: 65px;" class="wsod_aRight">Change</th>
        <th style="width: 65px;" class="wsod_aRight">%&nbsp;Change</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/quote/quote.html?symb=GE" class="wsod_symbol">GE</a> <span title="General Electric Co">General Electric Co</span></td>
            <td class="wsod_aRight"><span stream="last_136780" streamFeed="General Electric Co">6.50</span></td>
            <td class="wsod_aRight"><span stream="change_136780" streamFeed="General Electric Co"><span class="negData">-0.30</span></span></td>
            <td class="wsod_aRight"><span stream="changePct_136780" streamFeed="General Electric Co"><span class="negData">-4.41%</span></span></td>
```

Here is the code I used to isolate the table:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeatifulSoup as bs
    url=requests.get('https://money.cnn.com.data/hotstocks/")
    soup=bs(url.content, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt'}).text)
```

The created table contains this output:

```
Company
Price
Change
% Change

GE General Electric Co
6.50
-0.30
-4.41
```

I need to extract only the 'GE' portion of this output. Any help?

I'm also assuming there is a much easier way to do this without isolating the table at all

Comment: To clarify you looking to include the price / change in the output or just "GE" only?

Comment: first get `table` without `.text` and next search inside table `table.find('a').text` ?

Comment: @RBowen just looking to extract the GE only

Comment: why don't use `class="wsod_symbol"` to get this text ?

Comment: @furas the web page is much larger than the code I included, and many class="wsod_symbol" exist within it. That's why I first isolated the table.

Comment: then use `table.find('a', class="wsod_symbol")`  to search only in this table

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

On this I'm only selecting the first table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url=requests.get('https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/')
soup=bs(url.content, 'html.parser')

#find the tables
tbls = soup.find_all("table", class_="wsod_dataTable")

#select the first table
tbl1 = tbls[0]

#get all a tags 
records = tbl1.find_all("a", class_="wsod_symbol")
#pull out text only
records = [r.text for r in records]
```